# DIV animated from overflow:hidden area is not displayed on Safari iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, css

I found probably bug in Safari iOS, when animating DIV, that is translated out of container DIV. Look at this page: https://editor.triobo.com/v382/animace.html

DIV with logo has absolute position inside his container. Click on orange button starts animation and logo is translated out of container - this is correct. But: When this animation is played back, DIV is hidden and shown only if animation is finished.

Comments:

- if DIV doesn't contain image, but has only background-color, animation is correct.
- common tricks doesn't work: translate3d (to enforce 3d engine), setting perspective to 99999px, setting backface visibility…
- everything is ok on desktop safari, desktop Chrome, Android…
- if DIV is translated even one pixel less, than it should be, animation is correct (but this pixel is visible, so this solution is not good)

I have trick: add transparent space to inner DIV to fulfill condition "at least one pixel has to be overlaping", but this is just workaround…

What am I doing wrong? Is there really such bug in Safari iOS?